Mean reversion of a time series dependent on another time series
I am looking at a time series $x_t$ that is understood to be dependent on another time series $p_t$.
I want to set up a process where I randomly simulate $p_t$ and determine $x_t$ from the simulation.
To give context, suppose $p_t$ is the price of "widgets", and $x_t$ is the price of "fancy widgets".  The "fancy" implies that $x_t > p_t$ or alternatively $x_t = p_t + \delta_t$ where $\delta_t > 0$.
The general understanding is that as $p_t$ increases, $\delta_t$ will reduce, but as prices stabilize then $\delta_t$ will revert to its long term mean level.  Alternatively, as $p_t$ decreases, then $delta_t$ will increase in the short term but then revert.
Using the following as a resource:
http://marcoagd.usuarios.rdc.puc-rio.br/revers.html , I see that I can estimate the parameters of an AR(1) process for a single variable as:
$\delta_t - \delta_{t-1} = a + b\delta_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$
and regress to find the parameters $a$ and $b$.
If I wish to incorporate $p_t$ into the model, can I do so with
$\delta_t - \delta_{t-1} = a + b\delta_{t-1} + cp_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$
where $c$ is the effect of $p_t$ on $\delta_t$?
Sorry for the janky question.  I lack the appropriate vernacular to ask the question succinctly.  I tried searching for "cointegrated mean reversion" but couldn't find anything.

Isn’t that just a VECM model?
